# Why I couldn't access object's property?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate Vec2 object's properties (x and y) in `onDocumentKeyDown()` function which is in event.js. Why I couldn't access vec2's property in `onDocumentKeyDown()` function?

file: event.js

```js
function onDocumentKeyDown(event, vec2){
    var x_p = vec2.x;    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    var y_p = vec2.y;
    ...
```

file: app.js

```js
function init(){
    ...
    var vec2 = new Vec2(0,0);

    function animate (time) {
        ...

        document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
        vec2 = onDocumentKeyDown(event, vec2);
        obj.move(vec2);
        ...
        startTime = time;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    animate(0);
}
```

Vec2 class (Vec2.js):

```js
class Vec2{
    x;
    y;
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    ...
}
```

index.html:

```html
    .....
    <script src="vec2.js"></script>
    <script src="lib.js"></script>
    <script src="event.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just remove `x; y;` before the constructor

Comment: because onKeyDown when onDocumentKeyDown is invoked it is just passed the event

Comment: `document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false)` The function will receive the keydown event, but how would it receive a `vec2` argument here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you addEventListener as `onDocumentKeyDown` it is just passed an event value and not the `vec2` as argument.

You can use `.bind` method to pass on the custom arguments. However you would need to change the order in which you receive arguments  like

```
   function onDocumentKeyDown(vec2, event){
    var x_p = vec2.x;    
    var y_p = vec2.y;
    ...
    }
    function init(){
        ...
        var vec2 = new Vec2(0,0);

        function animate (time) {
            ...
            const fn = onDocumentKeyDown.bind(this, vec2);
            document.addEventListener("keydown", fn , false);
            vec2 = onDocumentKeyDown(vec2, event);
            obj.move(vec2);
            ...
            startTime = time;

            window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
        animate(0);
    }
```

Since you wouldn't want to change the argument order to onDocumentKeyDown, you can make use of arrow function

```
function onDocumentKeyDown(event, vec2){
    var x_p = vec2.x;
    var y_p = vec2.y;
    ...

}

function init(){
    ...
    var vec2 = new Vec2(0,0);

    function animate (time) {
        ...
        const fn = (event) => onDocumentKeyDown(event, vec2);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", fn , false);
        vec2 = onDocumentKeyDown(vec2, event);
        obj.move(vec2);
        ...
        startTime = time;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    animate(0);
}
```

P.S. Since you need to pass the same instance of function to removeEventListener that you passed to addEventListener, we can store the binded function to a seperate variable

Comment: Thanks, it works. I didn't know that how to give argument to the event functon. But chrome console gives same error with this code `var x_p = vec2.x;`.

Comment: Probably you don't need `vec2 = onDocumentKeyDown(vec2, event);` call. It depends on your implementation though